# appending characters to string in python

Tags: python, algorithm

I've been asked to write a program that simulates the MU game: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MU_puzzle

> Suppose there are the symbols M, I, and U which can be combined to produce strings of symbols. The MU puzzle asks one to start with the "axiomatic" string MI and transform it into the string MU using in each step one of the following transformation rules:

```
Nr.   Formal rule   Informal explanation                           Example
---   -----------   --------------------------------------------   --------------
1.    xI → xIU      Add a U to the end of any string ending in I   MI to MIU
2.    Mx → Mxx      Double the string after the M                  MIU to MIUIU
3.    xIIIy → xUy   Replace any III with a U                       MUIIIU to MUUU
4.    xUUy → xy     Remove any UU                                  MUUU to MU
```

This is what I have so far:

```
string = input("Enter a combination of M, U and I: ")

while True:
    if string and all(c in "MIU" for c in string):
        print("This is correct")
        break
        continue
    else:
        print("This is incorrect")
        break

rule = input("Enter a rule 1-4 or q to quit: ")

rule1 = (string+'U')

while True:
    if rule == ('1') and string.endswith('I'):
    print(rule1)
    break
    continue
elif rule == ('2') and string.startswith('M'):
```

However, I am stuck on the second rule.  I assume its asking me *to print the string from starting point 1 in range of the string* because M would be point 0, then add them together to form a new string? I'm not entirely sure how to do this.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code

Comment: whats wrong with it? it works when i execute it

Comment: Something like `s = 'M' + s[1:] * 2`?

Comment: No, the code as displayed will not execute. You will get an indentation error after `if rule == ('1')...`, and your last `elif` is dangling.

Comment: perfect, thankyou this is what I was looking for

Comment: I suggest you do some more simple Python tutorials, such as [Google's Python Class](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/). You'll find that solving problems like this become easier if you try to at least get a good foundation of knowledge and some practice.

Comment: ok i'll check it out, thankyou

Comment: Unless you're specifically asked to do this in Python, I think the right tool for the job is `sed`. It's possible to encode each rule with a corresponding `s` command in `sed`, which is both elegant and terse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways to implement rule 2 could be:

```
if string1.startswith(('M')):
    sub=string1[1:]
    rule2=('M'+sub+sub)
    print rule2
```

Answer (score 1):

How about following? I tried out using `python` inbuilt methods to manipulate `string`.
Since I am using Windows and Python 2.7, I had to convert `input` to `raw_input`

Also avoid using `python` `reserved words` like `string` as `variables`. It may cause  issues with python getting confused between `variables` and `literals`

**Demo Code:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
myStr = raw_input("Enter a combination of M, U and I: ")

while True:
    if myStr and all(ch in "MIU" for ch in myStr):
        print("This is correct")        
        break
    else:
        print("This is incorrect")
        break

rule = raw_input("Enter a rule 1-4 or q to quit: ")

#Rule 1
# xI→xIU ; Add a U to the end of any string ending in I; e.g.   MI to MIU   
if rule == '1' and myStr.endswith('I'):        
    newStr = "".join((myStr,'U'))
    print newStr

#Rule 2
# Mx → Mxx ; Double the string after the M  ;MIU to MIUIU
elif rule == '2' and myStr.startswith('M') and not myStr.endswith('I'):
    newStr = "".join((myStr,myStr[1:]))
    print newStr
```

**Output:**

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Enter a combination of M, U and I: MI
This is correct
Enter a rule 1-4 or q to quit: 1
MIU
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Enter a combination of M, U and I: MU
This is correct
Enter a rule 1-4 or q to quit: 2
MUU
>>>
>>> 
Enter a combination of M, U and I: MIU
This is correct
Enter a rule 1-4 or q to quit: 2
MIUIU
>>>
```